# Twilio: Modify route settings for multiple phone numbers using Twilio CLI

Tags: twilio

New to Twilio...and trying to setup newly imported DID's in the Twilio console.
Looking for advice on how to modify route settings for multiple DID's in our Twilio account. Needing to modify "Configure with" to point to SIP Trunk.

Looks like Twilio CLI might be best bet, but unsure how to do multiple numbers at once...

Any tips would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Twilio Console allow you to bulk assigned DID's, just:

Click: Elastic SIP Trunking > Trunks > Your SIP Trunk > Numbers > (+) > Add an Existing Number or Bulk Add an Existing Number

You can use the Twilio CLI but you would need to add some scripting on your own to cycle through the number assignments to the Elastic SIP Trunk.

`twilio api:core:incoming-phone-numbers:update --sid PNxxx --trunk-sid=TKxxx`